# How to get bold-italic faces in org-mode docs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In emacs it's easy to get `*bold*`, `_underline_`, or `/italic/` lettering, but is there a way to get combinations thereof? I tried a few combinations of symbols, but it looks like once one is enabled, the rest inside is essentially verbatim. I checked the manual, but didn't see anything on the subject.

Comment: If you place your cursor to the left of the character that you would like to bold/underline/italic (e.g., assuming your cursor is a vertical line), what is the font face that is being used when you type:  `C-u C-x =` ?

Comment: `xft:-unknown-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x4C)` is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Would love to know if you ever found a solution to this!

Answer (score 1):

also, in [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode), <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> key sequence runs the function `org-emphasize` which prompts for a character (one of `*`, `_`, `+` etc) and can act on a marked region;

as for combining both `_*text*_` and `*_text_*` constructs render correctly when exported to [html](/questions/tagged/html) ([`org-html-export-to-html`](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-Export-commands.html#HTML-Export-commands))

Answer (score 0):

The following Elisp code adds the emphasis characters to the pre and post components of `org-emphasis-regexp-components` (if they are not already present).
Afterwards it uses `org-set-emph-re` to re-compile the regexps for emphasis.
That enables sequences of multiple emphasis characters like `*/some text/*`.

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(require 'cl-lib)
(with-eval-after-load 'org
    (let ((emph-chars (apply #'concat (mapcar #'car org-emphasis-alist))))
      (cl-macrolet ((add-emph
             (place)
             `(unless (cl-search emph-chars ,place)
            (setf ,place (concat ,place emph-chars)))))
    (add-emph (car org-emphasis-regexp-components))
    (add-emph (cadr org-emphasis-regexp-components))))
    (let (dummy)
      (org-set-emph-re 'dummy nil)))
```

Tested with `emacs -Q` version 26.3.